# Cant remove bottom margin from drop down list inside centered DIV

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, html-lists

I have a 100% wide DIV that contains a centered navigation menu and nothing else.  The navigation menu is created using html lists and has some drop-down elements in it.

When you hover over a link in the navigation menu, the background color of that link changes, so naturally I don't want any visible top/bottom margins between the navigation menu and the DIV container - however, the menu is adding a 5px bottom margin which makes the design less attractive.

Here's what I'm having trouble with. I'm trying to use a responsive-design so the page can easily adapt between different browser resolutions, so I cannot specify an exact height for the DIV/nav bar.  I need the DIV/nav bar's height to automatically adjust so it can contain the navigation elements for screens with smaller resolutions.

I can get the margin removed without the drop down menu, and I can get it to work without having the navigation centered, but I cannot get the margin removed while keeping the drop down menu and having it centered.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XJRHy/

HTML code:

```
<div class="navigation">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navigation {
width: 100%;
height:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:#c0c0c0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

nav {
text-align: center;
width:100%;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size:1.375em;
}

nav ul ul {
display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
nav ul li {
    float:left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4289a9;            
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }
    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        color: #000000; text-decoration: none;
        font-weight:bold;
    }       
nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
    z-index:5000;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
        z-index:5000;

    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
            color: #fff;
            z-index:5000;

        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
                z-index:5000;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    z-index:5000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it as follows:

```css
nav ul {
    border: 1px solid blue; /* for demo only */
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

`nav ul` is an inline element with some white space below the base line.

Use `vertical-align: top` to remove it.

**[See Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/kcg82/)**

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for your help you've saved me from pulling out what remaining hair I have on my head.